# Using KF5 with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5

I'm trying to use the [KPlotting](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kplotting/html/index.html) widget with a Qt (v5.14) project that uses CMake (v3.10.2).

I installed the [KDE Extra CMake Modules](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/extra-cmake-modules/) by cloning the repo, then running: `cmake`, `make`, `sudo make install`.

I added `find_package(KF5Plotting)` to my top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file, and `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} KF5::Plotting)` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file in my `src` directory. However, when I compile I get the following error:

```
ui_mainwindow.h:30:10: fatal error: kplotwidget.h: No such file or directory
 #include <kplotwidget.h>
```

This *seems* to indicate that the call to `find_package` didn't work, but I'm unsure how to check. Am I simply missing an include directory directive in CMake? Any help on how to get this to compile would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
If I add `REQUIRED` to `find_package`, nothing *seems* to change, and the output is simply:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'portaudio-2.0'
--   Found portaudio-2.0, version 19
-- Found hamlib library at: /usr/local/lib/libhamlib.so
-- Found hamlib static library at: /usr/local/lib/libhamlib.a
-- Found hamlib static modules: 
-- Found hamlib include directory at: /usr/local/include
-- Found sox library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsox.so
-- Found sox headers: /usr/include
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
-- Found FFTW: /usr/include  found components:  FLOAT_LIB 
boost lib: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so
boost inc:/usr/include
fftw lib: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_threads.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_threads.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_threads.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_omp.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_omp.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_omp.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/wspeirs/src/sdhr/build
```

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file can be found here: https://gist.github.com/wspeirs/1948869bf7fdb6f943c143b2a223fa54

Also, I installed KPlotting via apt (`libkf5plotting-dev` & `libkf5plotting5`) on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What is the output of your CMake when you run from *your* top-level CMake file? Is `KF5Plotting` actually found? You should use `find_package(KF5Plotting REQUIRED)` to *require* it to be found. It would also be helpful to see your *full* CMake file.

Comment: Maybe `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC KF5::Plotting)`?

Comment: @arrowd adding `KF5::Plotting` to `target_link_libraries` lets the linker work, but doesn't solve the include problem.